# Zoo Visitor / Not Functioning Properly /

Tags: zoo-visitor

I've used Zoo Visitor 1.3.30 without problems on a EE 2.5.5 build but I'm having all kinds of problems with "nothing happening" when using any of the forms. I'm assuming I'm just missing something simple (at least that's what I'm hoping for!) but for the life of me I can't figure it out :(

All of the troubleshooting checks out fine:

[image]

As well as the Installation part of things:

[image]

I tried using Structure to setup my templates (that's what I did with the 2.5.5 build) and forms wouldn't submit so I copied over the entire Zoo Visitor Example templates (to it's own template group) and those wouldn't update either.

You can see them both in action here:

http://acs.planetmediaserver.com/profile
http://acs.planetmediaserver.com/zoo_visitor_example

I even turned off everything that I could in the Member Preferences section:

[image]

What else could I try to check?

**UPDATE**

Here's what my registration form looks like and again it's just a copy of what Zoo gives you:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form return='profile/register/success'}

<h3>Register</h3>
<fieldset>
    <h4>Extra fields</h4>

    <p>
        <label for="member_firstname">{label:member_firstname}:</label>
        <input type="text" name="member_firstname" id="member_firstname" value="{if member_firstname}{member_firstname}{/if}"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="member_lastname">{label:member_lastname}:</label>
        <input type="text" name="member_lastname" id="member_lastname" value="{if member_lastname}{member_lastname}{/if}"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="member_gender">{label:member_gender}</label>
        {options:member_gender}
        <input type="radio" id="member_gender" name="member_gender" value="{option_value}" {checked} />{option_value}
        {/options:member_gender}
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="member_address">{label:member_birthday}</label>
        <input type="text" name="member_birthday" id="member_birthday" value="{member_birthday}" maxlength="23" size="25"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
<br/>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Native member field</legend>
    <p>Mative member fields like location, url, signature, etc... can be handled by creating a channel field with the same name prefixed with "_member"
        For example member_signature will sync to the signature field. Custom member fields can be handled in the same way. Just create a channel field prefixed with "member_" and the value
        will also be saved to the profile.</p>

    <p>
        <label for="member_signature">Native member signature</label>
        <input type="text" name="member_signature" id="member_signature" value="{if member_signature}{member_signature}{/if}"/>
    </p>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <h4>Login details</h4>

    <p>
        <label for="username">Email*:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="{if email}{email}{/if}"/>
        <br/>(this will be your login/username if 'use email as username' has been set)
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="password">Password*:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="{if password}{password}{/if}"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="password_confirm">Confirm password*:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" value="{if password_confirm}{password_confirm}{/if}"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="terms_of_service">Terms of service:</label>
        <textarea name='terms' rows='4' readonly>All messages posted at this site express the views of the author, and do not necessarily reflect the views of the owners and administrators
            of this site.By registering at this site you agree not to post any messages that are obscene, vulgar, slanderous, hateful, threatening, or that violate any laws. We will
            permanently ban all users who do so.We reserve the right to remove, edit, or move any messages for any reason.</textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="accept_terms">Accept terms of service?*</label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='accept_terms' value='y' {if accept_terms == "y"}checked="checked"{/if} />
    </p>

    {if captcha}
    <p>
        <label for="captcha">{lang:captcha}*</label>
        {captcha}<br/>
        <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px;"/>
    </p>
    {/if}
</fieldset>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="form-submit"/>
</p>
<p>* Required fields</p>

{/exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form}
```

Thanks again for all of the help recently!

Comment: I also removed my .htaccess file and updated paths in my forms to include the /index.php/profile links to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was an .htaccess problem. Which is strange to me because I have the same .htaccess for other sites. But I suppose this thing happens from time to time. Time to re-evaluate what I'm doing in my htaccess file :)

Nico at EE Zoo is amazing! Great way to start the day :D

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to see the template code you are using.

Whilst the Addon may appear to be working for you on the site, it is highly likely that it is incompatible with that version.

Read upwards of the improvements and in particular to File upload, authorisation methods and Safecracker changes:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-5-5

The updates made for Zoo Visitor accomodate some serious changes, in particular the past few major point releases of EE. These notes explain the updates but are not dated for release:

http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/release_notes.html

I would suggest you try an earlier version of Zoo Visitor and see if the issue is replicated. You may need to call out on Twitter for assistance in getting an outdated version as there is no repository available publicly.

Comment: I just updated my original post! I think I'm going to email Zoo about this too. I posted in their forums but haven't heard anything yet.